# Heatmap for a large matrix and get the clear labels

Tags: r, matrix, heatmap, large-data

How to draw a heatmap from a matrix of 305 columns and 865 rows in R.

The code I have written for the matrix is

```
nba <- read.csv("mydata.csv", sep=",")

row.names(nba) <- nba[,1]
nba <- nba[,2:865]

nba_matrix <- data.matrix(nba)
nba_heatmap <- heatmap(nba_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = brewer.pal(9, "Blues"), scale="column", margins=c(5,10))
```

Now the code gives me the heatmap as shown bellow, but the labels are not clear. Please help me to get a clear heatmap.

[image]

Comment: please specify what you mean by "not clear". Do you want to get rid of the labels?

Comment: I want the labels to be clearly seen

Comment: There will be 865 labels, it will be extremely hard to see them if you reduce font-size to avoid overlap. Think about whether you really need all that information.

Comment: Yes I need all the informations, there will be 305 labels in Y axis and 865 labels in X axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you stated that you need all the labels, the only way I see is reducing the font size. You can do this by setting the `cexCol` and `cexRow` parameters in your call to `heatmap()`; for example like this:

```
heatmap(as.matrix(iris[,1:3]),cexRow = 0.1, cexCol = 0.1,)
```

Comment: Thanks but it is still the same... No changes in the picture

Comment: have you tried varying cexRow and cexCol? I just gave 0.1 as an example for the iris dataset, you probably have to pick a smaller value.